# My AxesLabel appears too far from the axis in SphericalPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

Any ideas on what I should do to make the "x", "y" and "z" labels appear at the ends of the axes.

Thanks in advance.

```
SphericalPlot3D[((Sqrt[1/2])*(1/Sqrt[2])*(1/Sqrt[2*Pi]) + (Sqrt[
       1/2])*(Sqrt[3]*Sin[theta]/2)*(Cos[phi]/Sqrt[Pi]))^2, {theta, 0,
   Pi}, {phi, 0, 2*Pi},
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[Opacity[0.2]]}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 Mesh -> 100, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.1],
 Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Opacity[0.4]], 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 Ticks -> None, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: :(]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we doesn't using `Tick` in axes, it is recommend to draw the axes manually.

```
plot = SphericalPlot3D[((Sqrt[1/2])*(1/Sqrt[2])*(1/
         Sqrt[2*Pi]) + (Sqrt[1/2])*(Sqrt[3]*Sin[theta]/2)*(Cos[phi]/
         Sqrt[Pi]))^2, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[Opacity[0.2]]}, 
   PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotLegends -> Automatic, Mesh -> 100, 
   MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.1], Axes -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Opacity[0.4]], Boxed -> False];
axes = Graphics3D[{{Brown, Arrowheads[.025], 
       Arrow@Tube@{{0, 0, 0}, #}, 
       Text[Style[x, Red, 25, FontFamily -> Times], #, {-2, 
         0}]} &[.35 {1, 0, 0}],
    {Brown, Arrowheads[.025], Arrow@Tube@{{0, 0, 0}, #}, 
       Text[Style[y, Red, 25, 
         FontFamily -> Times], #, {-2, -.5}]} &[.3 {0, 1, 0}],
    {Cyan, Arrowheads[.025], Arrow@Tube@{{0, 0, 0}, #}, 
       Text[Style[z, Red, 25, 
         FontFamily -> Times], #, {.1, -1}]} &[.2 {0, 0, 1}]}, 
   Boxed -> False];
Show[plot, axes]
```

[image]